# Get Copy Link Value from Document Library Files

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell, url, pnp, links

I am in the process of moving files to Sharepoint Online. Some of the files will have a share assigned to them (obtained via the 'Copy Link' option) in the format

https://myorg.sharepoint.com/:t:/s/mysite/SOME-lONg?StringOfCharsAndNumbers456778

I want to get a list of all links using the PnP Powershell Framework but cannot find the field in the ListItem or File object that contains the information. If i select the file in Sharepoint Online, i can see a link icon which has tooltip '1 link giving access' in the 'Has Access' Info panel.

I can get the relative URL information (https://myorg.sharepoint.com/mysite/mydocs/folder1/test.txt)

My script is as follows:

```
#Get Credentials
$creds = Get-Credential -UserName $user -Message "Enter password."

#Connect
Connect-PnPOnline –Url $site –Credentials $creds

#Get All Items to see which one i want
Get-PnPListItem -List $docLibrary

#get more info for my test file which has ID = 295
$checkItem = Get-PnPListItem -List $docLibrary -Id 295

#See all field values for the check item
$checkItem.FieldValues
```

I cannot see the link information in any of the field values.

I have also tried the File object but again, cannot obviously see where the information is.

```
$checkFile = Get-PnpFile -Url $link
```

Note: the $link in the above line is the relative URL

Is this possible using the PnP Framework and do i just need to dig further into the object to get what i need or is it not possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find a C# solution which uses the Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ObjectSharingInformation.GetObjectSharingInformation method thanks to this post:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/retrieve-sharing-links-information-for-a-sharepoint-item-using-csom
Thanks to @Srikanta Barik

For those of you looking for a similar solution, here is my code:

```
SecureString ss = new SecureString();
foreach (var cc in pwd)
{
  ss.AppendChar(cc);
}
var creds = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials(user, ss);

Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext context = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext(siteUrl);
context.Credentials = creds;
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Web w = context.Web;

//Load Web
context.Load(w);
context.ExecuteQuery();

//get list
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.List list = w.Lists.GetByTitle(doclib);

//create a query to limit to 100 for now
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery query = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery(1000);
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(query);

//load items
context.Load(items);
context.ExecuteQuery();

//loop through items
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ObjectSharingInformation sharinginfo = null;
foreach (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem item in items)
{
  sharinginfo = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ObjectSharingInformation.GetObjectSharingInformation(context, item, false, true, false, true, true, true, true);
  context.Load(sharinginfo);
  context.ExecuteQuery();

  if (sharinginfo != null && sharinginfo.SharingLinks != null)
  {
    foreach (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharingLinkInfo linkinfo in sharinginfo.SharingLinks)
    {
      
      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(linkinfo.Url))
      {        
        //export full relative file name and link
        Console.WriteLine("FileRef: {0}", item.FieldValues["FileRef"]);
        Console.WriteLine("Sharing Link Url: {0}", linkinfo.Url);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The C# solution is fine for me and i wont continue to find the equivalent PS one using Pnp or similar.